# ActionMailer randomly changing Message-ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailgun

I'm trying to track my message_id so that I can reply to track replies via the In-Reply-To field

However, it appears that the message_id that is set by ActionMailer randomly gets changed to a different ID?

I check the logs and they are not the same as the message_id that is set by action mailer.

```
message_mail = MessageMailer.campaign(message, message_user)
message_mail.deliver_later
message_user.message_reply_to = message_mail.message_id
```

Any idea why ActionMailer would change the message_id?

Comment: Referring [this](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail%2FMessage%3Amessage_id%3D), which part of your `message_id` is getting changed ?

Comment: Instead of '1234@message.id' it might end up as '2321@message.id' (essentially just a different random UUID)

I believe this is a rails bug,btw.  It does not happen if I use `deliver_now` only `deliver_later`  

I've [filed this bug on the rails project](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21220), once I get a response there I will update this SO post.

Comment: O i see. Thanks for giving the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is a serialization / cloning bug in ActionMailer.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21220